# Entropy in elimination theory, or a brief remark by Gelfand-Kapranov-Zelevinsky

Tags: reference-request, entropy, elimination-theory

In the introduction to their book "Discriminants, resultants and multidimensional determinant", the authors state a very intriguing observation concerning the coefficients of monomials appearing in $A$-discriminants, which are of the form $vol(\sigma_i)^{vol(\sigma_i)}$, for $\sigma_i$ a simplex ([page 5](http://books.google.de/books?id=n6ZxAKevSbsC&lpg=PA7&ots=joHagAfpT4&dq=discriminants%20resultants%20and%20multidimensional%20determinants&hl=es&pg=PA5#v=onepage&q&f=false)):

"The expression $\prod_ivol(\sigma_i)^{vol(\sigma_i)}$ (or, rather, its logarithm $\sum_i vol(\sigma_i) \log (vol(\sigma_i))$) brings to mind the entropy of a probability distribution. It would be interesting to find a "probabilistic" reason for its appearance in discriminants."

Does any know about the status of this observation, or about references discussing it?

Comment: For those of us intrigued by your question but without the book to hand, could you explain a bit more of the context?  Thanks.

Comment: There's now a link to the mentioned page, "courtesy" of Google Books.

Comment: Thanks.  The link didn't work for me ("you've reached your page viewing limit" or some such), but when I searched for it myself, I found it.  Google, eh.

Comment: The following certainly isn't an answer to your question, but I thought a bit about some related things a while ago; maybe there's some connection between discriminants and entropy via geometric invariants such as mixed volume.  See [here](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2011/08/mixed_volume.html), especially Mark Meckes's pointer to Richard Gardner's article.

Comment: That's a nice writing on mixed volume. I didn't know it so resembled the determinant.